# Calculate working hours in a day against hours should have worked

Tags: php, time

How to a calculate hours that are worked in a day?

```
Employee should work 8 hours so  8 x 3600 = 28,800 second lets say the employee only works for 4 hours 4 x 3600 = 14,400 so the result would be 14,400 - 28,800 = -14,400 so how do i convert the result to hours and minutes and seconds
RESULT =  - 04:00:00

also lets say 8 hours should work 8 x 3600 = 28,000 seconds lets say the employee works 12 hours 12 x 3600 = 43,200 = 43,200 seconds result would be 43,200 - 28,000 = 15,200
RESULT =  + 04:00:00

  <?php 
$hoursworked = 4*3600
$dd = 8*3600;
                        echo    gmdate("H:i:s", $dd%86400);     

            // day total            
        $ee =$hoursworked - $dd ;
                $seconds = $ee; 

        $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
        $mins = floor(($seconds - $hours*3600) / 60);
        $s = $seconds - ($hours*3600 + $mins*60);

        $mins = ($mins<10?"0".$mins:"".$mins);
        $s = ($s<10?"0".$s:"".$s); 

        $timea = ($hours>0?$hours.":":"").$mins.":".$s; ?>
```

The result I would like from the above example is -04:00:00 because the employee as only worked 4 hours and should have worked 8 Thanks

Comment: PHP isn't one of my primary languages, but it must be popular enough that a solution is available for something as ubiquitous as date/time math.  In general, it's probably going to be a combination of integer division and mod.

Comment: You need output in Hours only like 12:00:00 or like 12:05:45

Comment: Why is noone here mentioning `\DateTime` and `\DateTime::diff` ? Manually calculating times = stone-age :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code once.

```
function calc($work_hr, $tot_hr)
{
    $tot = $tot_hr * 3600;
    $work = $work_hr * 3600;
    if ($tot > $work) {
        $seconds = $tot - $work;
        $total = "- " . gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);
    } else {
        $seconds = $work - $tot;
        $total = "+ " . gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);
    }
    return $total;
}
echo "Less Hours :" . calc(4,8);  //Output : - 04:00:00
echo "<br>";
echo "Extra Hours:" . calc(12,8); //Output : + 04:00:00
echo "<br>";
echo "Extra Hours:" . calc(9.5,8); //Output : + 01:30:00
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Welcome brother..Please do vote will be useful further. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
<?php

function formatTime($hours) {
    $seconds = $hours * 3600;

    $worked = $hours - 8;
    $formatedhours = sprintf("%02d", abs($worked)) . ':00:00';

    // WHEN WORKED FOR LESS THAN ONE HOUR
    if($hours < 8) {
        $formatedhours = '-' . $formatedhours;
    }

    return $formatedhours;
}

$hours = 8; //hours
echo formatTime($hours);
```